# How to use generic function parameter

Tags: java, generics, methods, generic-programming

I would like to use one method for two types and I tried like this:

```
private <T extends Base> boolean isNeeded(String name, T receivedItem) {
    Base item = null;
    if (receivedRequest.getClass().equals(Derived1.class)) {
        item = (Derived1) receivedItem;
    } else if (request.getClass().equals(Derived2.class)) {
        item = (Derived2) receivedItem;
    }
    callMethodDoSomething(item.getData().getSpecificData());
}
```

But I do not know how to call a method which is only in the derived classes. Which is the best and safest way to do it?

Comment: It is rather difficult to understand what the actual problem is... It would makes things better if you provide the code that is actually calling the child class (classes) methods and is failing to compile. Is those calls supposed to be  in inside each ```if``` block right after each cast. Is the ```callMethodDoSomething``` a common treatment that item would receive regardless of whether it extends ```Derived1``` or ```Derived2```

Comment: Also the two cast ```(Derived?)``` are kind of useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what method overloading is for.

```
boolean isNeeded(String name, Derived1 item) { 
   return callMethodDoSomething(
        item.getData().getSpecificData());
}

boolean isNeeded(String name, Derived2 item) { 
   return callMethodDoSomething(
        item.getData().getSpecificData());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
boolean isNeeded(Base base) { 
    return callMethodDoSomething(base.getData().getSpecificData());
}
```

(Also skip the 'name' parameter since it is not used)